# sql-server which owner should i use?

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-server

i have about 10 scientists writing to a mysql database

i have migrated to sql server and now i have to deal with OWNERS

does it matter which owner i choose? when i do automate migration frmo mysql to sql server it assigns DBO. is that OK? should i continue to use that?

so now i have to do:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [rid]
      ,[filename]
      ,[qcname]
      ,[compound]
      ,[response]
      ,[isid]
      ,[isidresp]
      ,[finalconc]
      ,[rowid]
  FROM [test].[owner].[calibration]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all of your scientists used all of the tables in your previous database, it would probably be best to stay with DBO.  That is the least complicated, and if you don't need the additional schemas, don't make it more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the default owner (really, schema, if you're using SqlServer 2005 or later), you can use the default (which is dbo).

For more information about the differences between owners and schemas, which are somewhat related, take a look [here](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/understanding-the-difference-between-owners-and-schemas-in-sql-server).